# how to bubble up isPending (from useTransition) to ancestor components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a rather boilerplate component called `ClientButton` that basically wraps a Server Action in `startTransition` to create an event handler:

```
'use client';

export default function ClientButton({ onClick, buttonText, className }: ClientButtonProps) {
    const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
    return <button className={className} onClick={async () => startTransition(() => onClick())}>{buttonText}</button>;
}
```

I'm trying to get the `isPending` state in its ancestor, which looks like this:

```
'use client';

import { useTransition } from 'react';
import LoadingOverlay from 'react-loading-overlay-ts';

export default function TicTacToeGame({ currentPlayer, grid, cellClickHandler }: TicTacToeStateProps) {
    const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

    return (
        <LoadingOverlay
            active={ isPending }
            spinner
            className='game'
            text='Processing...'
        >
            <Board
                currentPlayer={currentPlayer}
                grid={grid}
                cellClickHandler={cellClickHandler}
            />
            <ClientButton buttonText="New Game" onClick={newGame}/>
        </LoadingOverlay>
    );
}
```

`Board` has a child component that has a child component that has a child component that is a `ClientButton`. However, everything between `TicTacToeGame` and `ClientButton` is a server component (or at least, doesn't explicitly say 'use server' in the file).

Basically, all of the game logic is server-side. My understanding is that I can't use `useState` or `useContext` because of this.

As far as I can tell, `isPending` in `TicTacToeGame` always resolves to false.

Both `cellClickHandler` and `newGame` are functions from a file that has `'use server';` at the top. A simplified version:

```
'use server';

async function cellClickHandler(currentPlayer: TicTacToePlayer, column: number, row: number) {
    // getGameState() is a synchronous method that returns a local variable from a .ts file meant to be server-side-only but without 'use server' to avoid a bunch of async methods
    const currentState = getGameState();
    currentState.currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
    testDelay();
    revalidatePath('/tictactoe');
}

async function newGame() {
    const currentState = getGameState();
    currentState.currentPlayer = 'X';
    testDelay();
    revalidatePath('/tictactoe');
}

function testDelay() {
    const startTime = performance.now();
    while (performance.now() - startTime < 5000) {
        // Do nothing for 5s to emulate extremely slow code
    }
}
```

I found [this guide](https://medium.com/@stheodorejohn/usetransition-hook-a-comprehensive-guide-f8306299e685) that says to use `unstable_wrapCallback`, but this appears to have been removed, and I haven't been able to figure out the equivalent using modern React / Nextjs.

Everything seems to be working as expected *except* the LoadingOverlay never displays 'Processing...'. I tried adding an artificial delay to `cellClickHandler`/`newGame`, and while I don't see the update until the timer finishes, `isPending`

Is there a solution besides passing a kinda vacuous callback all the way down the chain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not thrilled with the solution I've come up with, but it seems to work...

```
function startTransitionWrapper<
    ArgumentTypes extends unknown[],
    FunctionType extends (...fnArgs: ArgumentTypes) => Promise<void> | Promise<undefined>
>(startTransition: TransitionStartFunction, func: FunctionType) {
    return async (...fnArgs: ArgumentTypes) => startTransition(() => func(...fnArgs));
}
```

and I replaced

```
<Board
    currentPlayer={currentPlayer}
    grid={grid}
    cellClickHandler={cellClickHandler}
/>
<ClientButton buttonText="New Game" onClick={newGame}/>
```

with

```
<Board
    currentPlayer={currentPlayer}
    grid={grid}
    cellClickHandler={startTransitionWrapper(startTransition, cellClickHandler)}
/>
<button onClick={startTransitionWrapper(startTransition, newGame)}>New Game</button>
```

I feel like this shouldn't really be necessary, but I guess it makes ClientButton unnecessary ‍♂️

If anyone has a better solution, I would love it!